# How to filter ListBox using TextBox from XAML and code in ViewModel, MVVM Light

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, listbox

What are the codes to use to filter out my `ListBox` as the user is typing in the `TextBox`?

The data in my `ListBox` is from database. I have used a `RelayCommand` to get all the details of an `Event` then place the details in an `ObservableCollection`. Then bind my `ListBox` to the `ObservableCollection` and a `TextBlock` to show the `Event Names`.

XAML code:

```
<TextBox  x:Name="txtSearch" Text="{Binding HomePage.TxtEntered , Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White" FontSize="30"  Height="57" Margin="19,10,19,0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,72,19,0">
    <ListBox Background="Black"  x:Name="listBox" FontSize="26" Margin="0,10,0,0" LayoutUpdated="listbox_layoutUpdate" ItemsSource="{Binding HomePage.SearchEventCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtEventName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding EventName , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Tapped="txtEventName_Tapped" IsTapEnabled="True" Foreground="White" Width="300" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="55"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

`RelayCommand` in `ViewModel`:

```
private RelayCommand _eventSearch;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the EventSearch.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand EventSearch
{
    get
    {
        return _eventSearch
            ?? (_eventSearch = new RelayCommand(
            async() =>
            {
                SearchEventCollection.Clear();
                var eventList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Event>().ToListAsync();

                foreach (Event ename in eventList)
                {
                    SearchEventCollection.Add(new Event
                    {
                        Id = ename.Id,
                        EventName = ename.EventName,
                        Date = ename.Date,
                        Location = ename.Location,
                        Desc = ename.Desc
                    });
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

`ObservableCollection`:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Event> _searchEventCollection = new ObservableCollection<Event>();

public static ObservableCollection<Event> SearchEventCollection
{
    get { return _searchEventCollection; }
    set { _searchEventCollection = value; }
}
```

`PropertyChange` in `ViewModel`:

```
public const string TxtEnteredPropertyName = "TxtEntered";

private string _txtEntered;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the TxtEntered property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public string TxtEntered
{
    get
    {
        return _txtEntered;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_txtEntered  == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _txtEntered  = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(TxtEnteredPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want a LINQ query to filter the listbox with the characters in the text box.?

Comment: ok can give it a try

Comment: ok on what you want to filter ID?

Comment: i want to filter event name

Answer (score 0):

try this with wild card search:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(EventName);

var display = SearchEventCollection
    .Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item.EventName))
    .ToList<string>();
```

or

```
var display = SearchEventCollection.Where(q=>q.EventName.ToLower().Contains(EventName));
```

Comment: well thanks but i dnt know where to add this code. And can you help me by doing the filtering through `mvvm`  i have also added a `propertychange` binded to the textbox. now i want to filter the listbox

Comment: Text="{Binding EventName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" so that it updates everytime a text is entered

Comment: and put that code in the method that is called whenever any text is enter in your textbox

Comment: not working for me any other option to filter the listbox

Comment: can you edit the question and put where are you filtering it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84176/discussion-between-user3411961-and-deshdeep-singh).